# How to save images in storage for all android versions and devices

Tags: java, android, storage, version, device

I need to save images in storage from my android application, my code is working but not for all devices and android versions.

i need some solution or code from you that can save my images in all device and android versions.

i need to store data into android folder for my application privacy. i'm wanna to use storage like whatsapp. whatsapp can store images, videos, document all is in storage/emulated/0/Android/media/ without spacial permission and access easily, so what can i do, how can i manage it.

but i got issue with some samsung device. to store images in file manager

**NOTE: I need to save images in all type android version like [Android version 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, etc...] and any device like, [MI, Samsung, Oneplus, etc....]**

Comment: Go for Internal storage directories. It's same for all android version https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Answer (score 0):

For all versions you can store to: storage/emulated/0/Android/data/APP_PACKAGE/.

Or in general to `getExternalFilesDir()`.

Also for all versions you can store to:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
       , "MyFolder");
```

Update: getExternalFilesDir is not private on Android Q-;

For an app private storage location for all versions use `getFilesDir()`.

For `media` use getExternalMediaDirs() available since Lollipop but not private on Q- And not private on higher versions for apps with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. And never for file manager apps.

Comment: hello @blackapps i understand what are you say, but i need to store data into android folder for my application privacy. i'm wanna to use storage like whatsapp. whatsapp can store images, videos, document all is in `storage/emulated/0/Android/media/` without spacial permission ,so what can i do any options or solutions? Thankyou.

Comment: Well i can not read this privacy  demand in your original post. There is no privacy for Android 9 and below now. Please update your post. And with getExternalFileDir() you have privacy for all versions. Then explain (in your post ) why `data` folder is no good and why you want `media`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Kotlin Code for Saving an Image to Internal Storage (Android 13)

You can optimize the code for saving an image to internal storage in Android using Kotlin with the following improved code:

```kotlin
private fun saveToInternalStorage(imageUri: Uri) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, imageUri.toString())
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, imageUri.toString())
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        }

        val contentResolver = this.contentResolver
        val uri: Uri? = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)

        uri?.let {
            val fileDescriptor = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(it, "w")?.fileDescriptor
            val inputStream: InputStream? = this.getUriInputStream(imageUri)

            inputStream?.use { input ->
                fileDescriptor?.let { descriptor ->
                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(descriptor)
                    val buffer = ByteArray(4096)
                    var bytesRead: Int

                    while (input.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    }

                    outputStream.flush()
                    outputStream.close()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```